# После удаления из манифеста активити ошибка

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fedia.regestration/com.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2118)
```

Как исправить ?

Тема :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

манифест :

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
```

Answer (score 3):

Проблема у вас с темой для активити. В данном случае у вас используется тема с `ActionBar`. Вариант решения данной проблемы - это определить тему на все приложение у которой родитель будет

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
      <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
      <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
      <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
      <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

И в манифесте в `application`

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Так вы сделаете тему для всех активити

Comment: Извините, но ето все было. Тема была создана, и подключена в манифесте.

Comment: тогда покажите это в вопросе

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Так у вас тема стоит `DarkActionBar` а у меня написано `NoActionBar`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.